# Calling a python script from a Node js file gives error Python3 not found

Tags: python, node.js, docker, express, child-process

I am calling a Python file from a node js function

```
  let argument = "'hoodie'";
const result = execSync(`python3 -c "import poc4; print(poc4.giveMe(${argument}))"`, { encoding: 'utf8', maxBuffer: 50 * 1024 * 1024, shell: '/bin/sh'});
console.log('result', result.toString().trim())
```

The file in python is like this

```
def giveMe(hoodie):
    return hoodie
```

When I am executing the node js script it is giving me the error

```
 {"output":[null,"","/bin/sh: python3: not found\n"],"pid":220,"signal":null,"status":127,"stderr":"/bin/sh: python3: not found\n","stdout":"","timestamp":"2023-07-06T09:35:07.254Z"}
```

This is the Docker config that is being used

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine3.17
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY . ./
RUN npm install
CMD ["node", "index.js"]

EXPOSE 8000
```

Though I have Python3.11 and Node js v16.13.2 installed in my system.
Please suggest the fix.

Comment: Note that there is an extra `3` in your headline as compared to your command.

Comment: What OS are you using? On modern linux, you'd rather call `python` instead of `python3`.

Comment: can you just try to remove shell key from execSync's second parameter